# Changing colors of raster images in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, images, raster

I would like to change the colors of a Photoshop PSD in Adobe Illustrator. Can a raster image's color be altered in Illustrator?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I'm aware, the only way to alter the colors of the pixels in a raster image is via [Phantasm](http://astutegraphics.com/software/phantasm/).

Or by using "tricks"... such as drawing a shape on top of the raster image, filling it with a color, then changing the shape's blend mode.

Ideally, all raster editing should be done in a raster application.

Answer (score 2):

no "proper" way. You could turn channels separately to bitmaps, save them as tiff and import them in AI.